# Can't handle strings in windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I have written a python 2.7 code in linux and it worked fine.

It uses

```
os.listdir(os.getcwd())
```

to read folder names as variables and uses them later in some parts.

In linux I used simple conversion trick to manually convert the non asci characters into asci ones.

```
str(str(tfile)[0:-4]).replace('\xc4\xb0', 'I').replace("\xc4\x9e", 'G').replace("\xc3\x9c", 'U').replace("\xc3\x87", 'C').replace("\xc3\x96", 'O').replace("\xc5\x9e", 'S') ,str(line.split(";")[0]).replace(" ", "").rjust(13, "0"),a))
```

This approach failed in windows. I tried

```
udata = str(str(str(tfile)[0:-4])).decode("UTF-8")
asci = udata.encode("ascii","ignore")
```

Which also failed with following

```
DEM¦-RTEPE # at this string error occured

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1532, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\benhur.satir\workspace\Soykan\tkinter.py", line 178, in SparisDerle
    udata = str(str(str(tfile)[0:-4])).decode("utf=8")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa6 in position 3: invalid start byte
```

How can I handle such characters in windows?

NOTE:Leaving them UTF causes xlswriter module to fail, so I need to convert them to asci. Missing characters are not desirable yet acceptable.

Comment: `os.listdir(os.getcwdu())` (note the "u") will list the names as unicode strings.

Comment: Thanks this solved all. Anybody facing same, take a look at "ftfy" lib also. Combine it with os.getcwdu() and its all done!

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not like UTF8. You probably get the folder names in the default system encoding, generally win1252 (a variant of ISO-8859-1).

That's the reason why you could not find UTF8 characters in the file names. By the way the exception says you found a character of code `0xa6`, which in win1252 encoding would be `|`.

It does not say exactly what is the encoding on your windows system as it may depends on the localization, but it proves the data is not UTF8 encoded.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?
You can use this for optional `.replace()`
In the module of `string`, there is a set of characters that can be used..

```
>>> import string
>>> string.digits+string.punctuation
'0123456789!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
>>>
```

Comment: I cannot figure out what to replace with what.